# WordPress+IIS shows 404 for archives page with custom permalink /%category%/%postname%/

Tags: wordpress, iis, web-config, categories, permalinks

I need help.

I have the WordPress 4.0 and Microsoft-IIS/7.5 and custom structure of permalinks: `/%category%/%postname%/`

My web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page_id={R:0}"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The following links work fine

```
http://example.com/pageurl/  
http://example.com/posturl/  
http://example.com/blog/  
http://example.com/news/porsturl/  
http://example.com/articles/porsturl/  
http://example.com/category/articles/  
http://example.com/category/articles/page/3/
```

Site has "archives" block on blog page also. Links has such a format **http://example.com/`2014/04/`**, and this doesn't work. I got **404** error.

Please tell me what is wrong here?

Thanks.